# cannot access nav_header_main layout views

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I can not access the views present inside nav_header_main layout

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //setting profile picture in nav
    View emailview=navigationView.getHeaderView(2);
    View picview=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    View nameview=navigationView.getHeaderView(1);
    email_textview=(TextView)emailview.findViewById(R.id.emailtextView);
    profile_image=(ImageView)picview.findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);
    username_textview=(TextView)nameview.findViewById(R.id.appbarusernametextview);
    Intent intent =new Intent(this,EmailPasswordActivity.class);
    email=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
    email_textview.setText(email);
```

when i am using headerinflater it works but adds lots of header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing wrong way Change this code

```
View emailview=navigationView.getHeaderView(2);
View picview=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
View nameview=navigationView.getHeaderView(1);
email_textview=(TextView)emailview.findViewById(R.id.emailtextView);
profile_image=(ImageView)picview.findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);
username_textview=(TextView)nameview.findViewById(R.id.appbarusernametextview);
```

to this

```
 email_textview=(TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.emailtextView);
 profile_image=(ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);
 username_textview=(TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.appbarusernametextview);
```

Comment: thanks brother it worked...you saved my day..thanks alot

Comment: @user3297303 if it help you then accept the answer. so it will help other in future.

Answer (score 4):

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
email_textview = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailtextView);
profile_image = (ImageView)headerView(R.id.profile_imageView);
username_textview = (TextView)headerView(R.id.appbarusernametextview);
```

Try This Hope it will help you

Comment: bro i have tried it is giving error...cannot find views

Comment: your headerView in the xml should have the id nav_header_main

Comment: i just edit my answer try this one... it should also work

Answer (score 0):

for access to NavigationView Header Childs:

```
TextView lblUserName = (TextView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);
```